# LineBreakMeasurer produces result differ from MS Word / LibreOffice

Tags: java, swing, line-breaks, word-wrap, libreoffice

In a swing application, I need to foresee text wrapping of a string like when putting it in a word processor program such as MS Word or LibreOffice. Providing the same width of the displayable area, the same font (face and size) and the same string as following:

- displayable area width: 179mm (in a .doc file, setup an A4 portrait page - width = 210mm, margin left = 20mm, right = 11mm; the paragraph is formatted with zero margins)
- Font Times New Roman, size 14
- Test string: Tadf fdas fdas daebjnbvx dasf opqwe dsa: dfa fdsa ewqnbcmv caqw vstrt vsip d asfd eacc

And the result:

- On both MS Word and LibreOffice, that test string is displayed on single line, no text wrapping occurs.
- My bellow program report a text wrapping occurs, 2 lines

  Line 1: Tadf fdas fdas daebjnbvx dasf opqwe dsa: dfa fdsa ewqnbcmv caqw vstrt vsip d asfd

  Line 2: eacc

Is it possible to achieve the same text wrapping effect like MS Word in swing? What could be wrong in the code?

Bellow the my program

```java
public static List<String> wrapText(String text, float maxWidth,
        Graphics2D g, Font displayFont) {
    // Normalize the graphics context so that 1 point is exactly
    // 1/72 inch and thus fonts will display at the correct sizes:
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = g.getDeviceConfiguration();
    g.transform(gc.getNormalizingTransform());

    AttributedCharacterIterator paragraph = new AttributedString(text).getIterator();
    Font backupFont = g.getFont();
    g.setFont(displayFont);
    LineBreakMeasurer lineMeasurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(
            paragraph, BreakIterator.getWordInstance(), g.getFontRenderContext());
    // Set position to the index of the first character in the paragraph.
    lineMeasurer.setPosition(paragraph.getBeginIndex());

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int beginIndex = 0;
    // Get lines until the entire paragraph has been displayed.
    while (lineMeasurer.getPosition() < paragraph.getEndIndex()) {
        lineMeasurer.nextLayout(maxWidth);
        lines.add(text.substring(beginIndex, lineMeasurer.getPosition()));
        beginIndex = lineMeasurer.getPosition();
    }

    g.setFont(backupFont);
    return lines;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTextPane txtp = new JTextPane();
    frame.add(txtp);
    frame.setSize(200,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Font displayFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    float textWith = (179 * 0.0393701f) // from Millimeter to Inch
                        * 72f;           // From Inch to Pixel (User space)
    List<String> lines = wrapText(
            "Tadf fdas fdas daebjnbvx dasf opqwe dsa: dfa fdsa ewqnbcmv caqw vstrt vsip d asfd eacc",
            textWith,
            (Graphics2D) txtp.getGraphics(),
            displayFont);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("Line " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        System.out.println(lines.get(i));
    }
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for the question

From my experience with text editors it's not possible to achieve exactly the same measuring.

You can try to play with DPI there is default DPI=72 and 96 on windows.

Also you can try to play with all the rendering hints of the Graphics - text antialiasing etc.

Comment: I must admit that achieving the exact result is impossible. I tried to play with DPI and various rendering hints, but no luck. It seems that we have to live with the approximate measurement.